# Change IP address :: Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, internet, wireless-networking, ip-address

I am trying to access a website from an IP address that appears different than the normal one. I have tried using "sudo ifconfig 192.168.1.29 up" and successfully changed the ip address, but then I wasn't able to use Firefox, it just kept on loading. So I reset my connection, the router restored my normal IP address (It stores my MAC and gives me the same IP each time). Now I am back to where I started. Any ideas.

Note: I have very little idea what I am doing. Tell me if the question doesn't make sense. Please to answer in beginner friendly terms.

Answer (score 3):

You have two IP addresses; a local one (192.168.1.XXX) and a dynamic, public one from your ISP.

Websites you visit see your 'outside' address; not your 192.168.1.XXX one. If you want to change this address, try a DHCP release in your router. If you want to change your internal one, you could disable DHCP in your router or, ideally, create a DHCP lease so that you get a different IP every time.

For all of this, you should consult the documentation for your router. :-).

Comment: 192.168 addresses come under the private network addresses, basically meaning you can't use them over the net. You can read more about the RFC1918 here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Get so far, but how do I get a DHCP release in my router? Beginner terms.

Comment: This will depend on the make and model of your router. For example, on mine, I click the 'Status' tab and then click 'IP Address Release'.

You should consult the documentation for your router.

Comment: What? What screen/menu/login are you coming from? Are you talking about when you are loged into the router?

Comment: Usually you can login in your router. There is somewhere a menu where you can "update your ip address", "get a new release" or something similar. If you tell us your model, maybe we can give more specific advice.